How do I transfer data from stand alone hard drive
Hard drive stand alone out if tower. How can I remove the 25 years of docs and pictures from it to load in new computer. Is this even possible?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

(1) Photo(s) showing the drive will be helpful. Concentrate on showing its physical interface and the label. (2) New computer of what kind? A laptop? // Please do not respond in comments. [Edit] the question and add information there.
